# Which is more memory-efficient, static method or instance method in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management

When you create some instances of a class, each of them has a reference to the instance method, right?
I'm not sure whether each of them also have a reference to the static method. If so, there's no difference in memory efficiency between static method and instance method.
Thank you.